How to change size of page.drawer in Flet framework?
I'm creating my APP using Flet framework and I want to add a drawer, from tutorial I saw this
page.drawer = ft.NavigationDrawer(
        controls=[
            ft.Container(height=12),

            ft.NavigationDrawerDestination(
                label="Item 1",
                icon=ft.icons.DOOR_BACK_DOOR_OUTLINED,
                selected_icon_content=ft.Icon(ft.icons.DOOR_BACK_DOOR),
            ),
            ft.Divider(thickness=2),
            ft.NavigationDrawerDestination(
                icon_content=ft.Icon(ft.icons.MAIL_OUTLINED),
                label="Item 2",
                selected_icon=ft.icons.MAIL,
            ),
            ft.NavigationDrawerDestination(
                icon_content=ft.Icon(ft.icons.PHONE_OUTLINED),
                label="Item 3",
                selected_icon=ft.icons.PHONE,
            ),
        ],

    )


And it looks Ok , BUT I want change the width of it and the class ft.NavigationDrawer doesn't have 'width' argument. What should I do?
I've tried to go to the parent class but I couldn't find any size parameters either.
